# Radio button images not changing in swift

Tags: swift, radio-button

I have given loutlet for both buttons and images, and i have given tag = 0 to bankAccBtn and tag = 1 to paypalBtn

and for both buttons i have given one button action `radioBtn`, radio button not working, where am i wrong

```
class WithdrawFundsVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var paypalImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var bankAccImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var bankAccBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var paypalBtn: UIButton!
var btnArray = [UIButton]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    btnArray = [bankAccBtn,paypalBtn]
}


@IBAction func radioBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    for button in btnArray {
             if sender.tag == 0{
                 button.isSelected = true;
                bankAccImage.image = UIImage(named: "checked.png")
             }else{
                 button.isSelected = false;
                bankAccImage.image = UIImage(named: "unchecked.png")

             }
         }
    
}    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Change

```
if sender == button {
```

2- Create array of back images also instead of the single `bankAccImage`